# how to get values of my poll object?

Tags: java

I have my HashMap,

```
private final HashMap<Integer, Poll> pollmap = new HashMap<Integer, Poll>();
```

and my constructor is:

```
Poll(int id, String pollName, String question, String pollAnswerOptions[], boolean active)
```

How do I get the extract the Poll values such as pollname, question, etc FROM the pollmap hashmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer i = ... 
Poll poll = pollmap.get(i);
```

Then use whatever methods on the `Poll` object available to you to extract the values, e.g.,

```
poll.getId();
poll.getPollName();
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Poll objects, and then on each object the values, like this:

```
pollmap.get(key).getPollName
```

etc.